# Skip Layout event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I use the Layout Event Handler in order to set the focus to a specific field. So everytime the Layout event occurs, the focus will be set to that field.

My problem is that when I make something visible/invisible, the focus will be set again to this specific field which I don't want.

How to avoid that?

Is there a way to say "skip the Layout Event Handler next time" ?

or should I use another Event Handler instead of the Layout one?

I just want it to be set the first time, but the Load event does not seems to work as expected.

Code for Load event handler:
in the Designer.cs

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    // other stuff automatically generated by windows
    this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.myControl_Load);
    // other stuff automatically generated by windows
}
```

and in myControl.cs:

```
private void myControl_Layout(object sender, LayoutEventArgs e)
{
    this.myTimeEdit.Focus();
}
```

Comment: How are you doing it in Load event?

Comment: In the properties of the XtraUserControl, on the action Layout, I set a function doing the focus

Comment: Can you please post the code here? Do you mean in Layout eventhandler?

Comment: yes this is what i meant. Thanks for the vocabulary, I did not know how to call it

Comment: But you said you are doing in the Form_Load eventhandler? "but the Load event does not seem to work.."; Better if you post the code

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, you need to focus a particular control when a form is shown for the first time. First, you can try to set the [TabIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to 0. In this case, this control will be focused on the first form showing.

Try also to focus the control on the Form.Shown event instead of the Load event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`LayoutEventArgs.AffectedProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.layouteventargs.affectedproperty(v=vs.110).aspx) property. Just check if its value is set to `"Visible"`:

```
private void myControl_Layout(object sender, LayoutEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.AffectedProperty == "Visible")
        return;

    this.myTimeEdit.Focus();
}
```